# jQuery - log out on login attempt from new window or browser tab

Tags: jquery, session, authentication, tabs, logout

I saw on couple of websites that they manage to log you out automatically if you attempt to login on the same website on new browser window or tab.
There is such jQuery plugin? 
There is a way in jQuery to get the session value from one tab to another (on the same browser)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging out an already logged-in user is definitely a server-side feature. Any login requests should be handled by the server, which would have logic to say "A currently-anonymous user is requesting to log into this account, but this account is already logged in. Hm, better log it out for security!"

jQuery only exists on the client side, and while you can trigger server requests through Javascript the server still needs the logic to determine what to do with the request. However, using Websockets or a similar technology, a server could push the normal logout notification to the browser in real time, which could show the feature you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking is possible to get the session value in jquery and check against the session value on new login. If they match then redirect to logout page on the old tab. Everything start with the timeout plugin found it here: [link]http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/

Comment: That plugin does maintain a client-side timer, but ultimately communicates with the server using long polling for the actual logout. That validation still needs to be done on the server, for security and for the fact that an instance of jQuery on one computer can't read values from an instance on another computer.

Comment: I agree 100% but I need to logout on the same browser (but different tabs) for the same user. Ohh, yeah, they are stupid enough and work on many windows on the same time or open a new tab and then another tab and then forget on what tab they enter the info and then submit the form from the last tab opened.

Comment: Do you have the ability to add that functionality to the server? Looking more closely at the link you showed, it seems the actual goal of the timeout plugin is to deal with the *server's* timeout functionality, and provide the user a way to reset the timeout without losing any work. So, the plugin does not log out the user, it just lets them know that they are **going** to be logged out.

Comment: Yes, it is log them out. There is a logout url and I put my logout.php there and it's working fine. Log me out from all browsers after 10 minutes of inactivity on website. Just wondering how the auto logout can be done if you try to login again (server or client side) or not let me login if I'm already login on other tab or browser. I think I can do it server side with PHP and MySQL: store sessions on DB and check at login if there is an active login for this user. Use jQuery to update the login time every 60 sec. Something like that. Thanks.